# Install PECL extension in Ubuntu 16.04 with PHP 7.0.18

Tags: 16.04, php7

I am using an application in php that requires having PECL installed.
I was looking for but I can not find something clear that indicates how to do it.
Does anyone know how to do it? I use Ubuntu 16.04 and PHP 7.0.18.

Thanks for the help you can give me.

Answer (score 11):

You want to install `php-pear` which contains pecl. If you are using pecl to install other extensions you may also want to install `php7.0-dev` so phpize is available when installing pecl extensions.

Comment: use the command: `apt-get install php7.0-dev` or your current php version